# Removing hotspots from body using Lotus notes C API

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to remove hotspots from Note body using C API.
I know one way to do this:
1) `NSFNoteOpen(hDb, noteId, 0 /*NO FLAGS*/, &hNote);`
2) Enumerate all`TYPE_COMPOSITE` items, Keep appending all CD records in separate buffer except records between `SIG_CD_HOTSPOTBEGIN` and `SIG_CD_HOTSPOTEND`
3) remove this item and append newly created item.
4) `NSFNoteUpdate(hNote, UPDATE_FORCE);`

But problem is that, all Rich text infomations is lost

Is it possible to achieve the same when note is opened with
OPEN_RAW_MIME flag? There are no TYPE_COMPOSITE items in the note in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the type of the Body field and act accordingly. I.e., if the Body is stored as TYPE_COMPOSITE, you already know what to do. But if the Body is stored as TYPE_MIME_PART, you need to use the Notes C API calls whose names all start with "MIME". You can find these functions listed in the Notes C API Reference. Here are a couple of [blog](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F872571F100679B17) [posts](http://www.proudprogrammer.no/web/ppblog.nsf/d6plinks/RIVH-9RXLUR) that talk a bit about some related subjects.